# Center a character in svg

Tags: svg

I'm looking to produce a SVG file containing a single ascii character (say 'g' or 'W') from an arbitrary font centered within a 100 x 100 window. This is the closest I've got, but it's not quite right...

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <text x="50" y="50" font-size="100px" 
      text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="middle">g</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVG does not have automatic vertical layout capabilities on its own; you need something else to compute the height of the box, like JavaScript or…

Looks like you're embedding this inside of a web browser. If so, then you can use the automatic layout capabilities of HTML to do this for you, using `<foreignObject>` to embed an HTML snippet inside your SVG with `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle` on the content.

Comment: actually, in fine I'm trying to export to png using imagemagick, so no browser :(

Comment: @ArthurB. Ah, then that portion of my answer won't help. Why would you be using a DOCTYPE in your document then, though? FYI the recommended way to describe an SVG file is just: `<svg xmlns="…">` No DTD, no `version` attribute.

Comment: Copy paste I suppose ^^

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to centre text vertically in SVG.

The best you can to is work out where the baseline (`<text>` `y` attribute) should go for a particular font and group of characters (eg. all capitals).

Comment: Are you sure? The alignment baseline has a property "middle" which is close enough to the center of a character for my purpose...
See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/text.html#AlignmentBaselineProperty
and http://apike.ca/prog_svg_text_style.html

Comment: It depends on whether the SVG renderer supports `alignment-baseline` (AFAIK not all do) and that the font has a baseline table.  Also, it centres the font, not individual characters.